# Why doesn't my event handler work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I made a game with Unity and now I want to make a game launcher for it. I already start and I have a problem now. I use electron with Html, Css and want to use JS in the backend. I have an button with an ID and in JS I have an event handler for it.

Thats the inportant part of Html:

`<img id="startGame" class="instances-icon1" src="assets/icons8-add-48.png">`

And thats  the important part of Javascript:

```
const updateURL = 'https://www.dropbox.com/sh/smphut3qh3z40p6/AACHccLIURSjFd3a1vHrMmq4a?dl=1';
const executablePath = 'C:\Users\Linus\Documents\Bluci Runners\exe';

document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", function() {
  fetch(updateURL).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => fs.createWriteStream(executablePath).write(blob));
  console.log("Succes!");
})
```

The dropbox link is where Js shall download the game. My problem is that the event handler isnt working.

Comment: Are you sure the JS is executed after the DOM element is created?
If the JS is executed before the element is actually created in the DOM you will not be able to reference it.
Can you check the console for errors too and give more information?

Comment: You can also try the event delegation and can listen to the event to any parent element or body. Refer https://javascript.info/event-delegation for more info.

Please also share fiddle example to demonstrate the issue

Comment: Is that code to be run in a browser?  I don't think `fs.createWriteStream` exists in the browser, unless Electron lets you do that.

Comment: @vuryss I have the problem that I dont know, in which file I have to write i. I wrote it in main.js, where are also the code to create the electron window, etc

Comment: @
Mohit Raj Purohit what do you mean with fiddle example?

Comment: @
James no it dont run in the browser. It runs in a electron app.

Comment: You need to escape all the backslashes in `executablePath`.

Comment: @Barmar how can I do that?

Comment: Put a backslash before them: `const executablePath = 'C:\\Users\\Linus\\Documents\\Bluci Runners\\exe';`

Comment: Or use `/` instead of `\ `

Comment: @Barmar Ok I have it now with 2 backslash. But in witch file I have to write the Js? Because I wrote it in main.js, where are also the code to create the electron window, etc

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about electron, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Your Javascript can be placed in-between `<script>` tags after your closing `</body>` but before your closing `</html>` tag. Your Javascript refers to [`fs.createWriteStream()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatewritestreamoptions) which is a Node.js module method. You would not usually have access to Node in your render process unless you explicitly set `nodeIntegration` to `true` in  your windows `webPreferences`. Instead, you can use IPC to notify your main process that the 'start Game' button has been clicked and implement your fetch in the main process.